# File and folder structure is changed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, directory-structure

My **folder structure** of eclipse project is changed somehow and I am unable to **revert** it to previous view which led to certain difficulties.yes, This is quite embarrassing but it just happened.Below is a **screenshot** of what my file structure was looking before something changed.
[image]

> And now it has become something like this in below:

[image]

> PS:

To cut all things short and to make you understand.earlier file structure was simple with **build,src,WebContent, and .settings** but now it has become quite complex with addition of several folders of which I don't know the significant for ex:**JAX-WS Web Services** and also I was unable to extract the class file which was compiled through Java files.Thanks in advance.I don't know if its a good question or bad one , & it does not matter if you downvote me ,but atleast please save me from this hell. ☺

Answer (score 1):

Are you in the appropriate perspective ?

[image: Java perspective]

It's been 3 or 4 years I haven't done JavaEE, but I think there is also a JavaEE perspective.

```
Menu > Window > Open Perspective
```

Finally, your problem seems to come from the view you have selected :

```
Menu > Show View > Other > (General > Navigator)
```

In the last picture, you are in the "Project Explorer" view and in the other one in the "Navigator" view.

Comment: It does help but things aren't reverting to original. can you please elaborate a little about this.I mean which perspective was chosen in first image.thank you for your time.☺

Comment: Edit : Show View : General > Navigator